# start a process on cmd without waiting it (php)

Tags: php, node.js, server

I have to start a NodeJS server from my script in PHP without waiting for it. To get started the NodeJS server I use.

```
$command = "cd /d " . $row["pathServer"] . " && node server";
exec($command, $output);
```

but it doesn't work because the webserver waits until the command is finished. How can I separate the two processes?

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the `stdout` of  command to a file, if you want to see it later. But if you don't want it, just redirect to `/dev/null`

```
$command = "cd /d " . $row["pathServer"] . " && node server > /dev/null &";
exec($command);
```

Comment: I just tried to do it but when I search "localhost:port/index.html" on my browser, the NodeJs server not respond..

Comment: seem the node server not run. Please check by run that command directly in terminal

Comment: Yeah, Directly from cmd it work! I check also the path of the server and it's correct. 

Comment: I have edit the answer, and remove `$output` variable. Please check

Comment: nothing.. it doesn't work.. Do you know how can I check if the server it's started? I've try to check on task manager if the server appear but I don't find it

Comment: I've just seen that if I use $command = "cd /d " . $row["pathServer"] . " && node server";
exec($command, $output); and in another window, while the page load, I write "localhost:port/index.html", it work..

Comment: Just curious what is really happen. But you can redirect the output to another file if you want to see the output.
`node server > /tmp/node.log`. After run the php file, please check the file to see the output `tail /tmp/node.log`